# Show HTML5 validation only on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have the code below

```
 <input 
    required 
    pattern="[0-9]{5,10}"
    oninput="setCustomValidity('')" 
    oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Type something')" 
    />
```

When this element is focused and validation bubble is showing ,how to remove bubble `onkeyup` or at least change the message?

For example in below demo user submits form and leaves required filed empty then when typing the message bubble blanks and different message is showing up

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hyhesLf5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i guess i found the solution
for keep showing message the one i want i do this

```
if(typeof elm.validity !=='undefined')
    {
        if(typeof msg !=='undefined' && msg!='')
        {
            for(i in elm.validity)
            {
                if (elm.validity[i] === true && i !=='valid' )
                {
                    elm.setCustomValidity(msg);
                    return true;
                }else
                {
                    elm.setCustomValidity('');

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and for not blanking on focus i simply do this:

$(elm).blur();$(elm).focus();

I Will post Full example here:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hyhesLf5/6/)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure there is any way, you can turn-off html5 validation on form using `<form action="" method="post" novalidate>` attribute, but field level setting flexibility is not present. For this you should use some validation library

Here are some library you can try

- https://github.com/ryanseddon/H5F
- http://ericleads.com/h5validate/
- http://parsleyjs.org/